# Mapping an async function twice using two different .map()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, ecmascript-5

So, I have two arrays: clientFeatures (which contains id for each clientFeature in each index) and featureLocalIds (which contains id in each index) and I have to map each of those values in an async function. I know we can use Promise.all(mapFunctionWithAsync) for mapping an async function but how do I accomplish a double map?? My code looks like this:

Basically, I have to update the ClientFeature with clientFeatures.id's values in "id" field and featureLocalIds's values in "featureId" field of the ClientFeature model and I have to do that AT THE SAME TIME! I tried the code below but it just adds one featureLocalId to multiple clientFeatureIds

```
let clientFeatures = await ClientFeature.query("clientId")
    .eq(client.id)
    .exec();

  let featureLocalIds = agreementFeatures.clientFeatureId;

var clientFeaturesNew = featureLocalIds.map(async item => {
        let newClientFeatures = await Promise.all(
          clientFeatures.map(async clientFeature => {
            clientFeatureGen = await ClientFeature.update({
              id: clientFeature.id,
              clientId: client.id,
              featureId: item,
              enabled: true
            });
            return clientFeatureGen;
          })
        );
      });
```

Comment: Do you realize that `.map()` is not `async` or `promise` aware.  Using `await` inside the `.map()` callback does NOT pause the `.map()` operation until the `await` finishes.  So, any `.map()` that you pass an `async` callback to is just going to return to you an array of promises.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and Promise.all() helps in passing an async function in .map(). But I'm facing the issue with two .map() here. I have to access the values of different variables using loop at once.

Comment: Well, I don't understand what exactly you're asking.  `clientFeaturesNew` will be an array of promises that each resolve to an array of values.  To get the values from `clientFeaturesNew`, you would use `Promise.all(clientFeaturesNew).then(data => { /*code here*/})`.